# h:inputText data cached

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces, ajax4jsf, commandlink

1. Click "LINK1" --> modal popsup --> enter value in text-box --> click Submit/Process
2. Click another link "update/cancel" --> same modal popsup --> I see the value in the text box (This is fine and if I reload the page and click the link again, the modal appears with values intact)
3. Click "LINK1" --> same modal popsup --> I see the value in the text box cached(this time I want the values not to be cached in the text box) --> If I reload the page, the values go away though.

I have tried clearing the backing-bean when the links are clicked, but still the values appear. Please advise.

---

**Update** here is the code:

`ReimbursementActionBean.java`

```
@Name("reimbursementAction")

@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)

public class ReimbursementActionBean implements Serializable {

    public void initReimbursement(PaymentInfo payment) {
           // do something
    }

    public void initNewReimbursement(PaymentInfo payment) {
        initReimbursement(payment);
        // --> log.info("CLEARING INPUT ELEMENT CACHE");
        // -->this.getReimbursement().setAmount(null);
        hideModal = false;
    }

    public void initUpdateReimbursement(PaymentInfo payment) {
        initReimbursement(payment);
        hideModal = false;
    }

    public void initCancelReimbursement(PaymentInfo payment) {
        initReimbursement(payment);
        hideModal = true;
    }


   public void reimbursePayment() {
                 // do something
    }


    public void updateReimbursment() {
         // do something

    }

    public void cancelReimbursment() {
         // do something
    }


    public void cancelupdateReimbursment() {
        hideModal = true;
    }

    public Reimbursement getReimbursement() {
        return reimbursement;
    }

    public void setReimbursement(Reimbursement reimbursement) {
        this.reimbursement = reimbursement;
    }

}
```

`reimbursePaymentModal.xhtml`

```
< rich:modalPanel id="reimbursePaymentPanel"
                     width="430"
                     autosized="true"
                     showWhenRendered="#{!hideModal}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText value="Reimburse Payment"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>

        <h:form>
            <a4j:outputPanel id="reimbursePaymentDiv">
                <s:div styleClass="section" style="padding:5px;padding-left:0px;">

                    <s:decorate template="/layout/edit.xhtml">
                        <ui:define name="label">Reimbursement Amount(*)</ui:define>
                        <h:inputText id="reimbursementAmount"
                                     value="#{reimbursementAction.reimbursement.amount}">
                            <a4j:support event="onblur" rerender="reimbursementAmount" action="#{reimbursementAction.validateAmount}" limitToList="true" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </s:decorate>

                    <div style="clear:both"></div>

                </s:div>

                <div class="button-holder" style="padding-top:10px">

                    <div style="float:right">
                        <a4j:commandLink oncomplete="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('reimbursePaymentPanel');"
                                         immediate="true"
                                         action="#{reimbursementAction.cancelupdateReimbursment()}"
                                         styleClass="button"
                                         reRender="reimbursePaymentPanel">
                            <!--todo add cancel command to reimbursementAction-->
                            <span class="inner-button">Cancel</span>
                        </a4j:commandLink>
                    </div>


                    <div style="float:right">
                        <a4j:commandLink id="reimbursePaymentId" styleClass="button"
                                         oncomplete="this.disabled=false;"
                                         action="#{reimbursementAction.reimbursePayment}"
                                         rendered="#{reimbursementAction.reimbursementConstraints.allowableReimbursementAction eq 'SUBMIT_NEW'}"
                                         reRender="paymentSearchResults,reimbursePaymentDiv,reimbursePaymentPanel,pnlInfoView" limitToList="true"
                                         bypassUpdates="true" onclick="this.disabled=true;">
                            <span class="inner-button">Process</span>
                        </a4j:commandLink>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a4j:outputPanel>

        </h:form>

    </rich:modalPanel>
```

`PaymentList.xhtml`

```
< a4j:outputPanel id="paymentSearchResults" ajaxRendered="true">

        <s:div styleClass="section" style="overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;max-height:420px;margin:10px "
               rendered="#{not empty paymentList}">
            <rich:dataTable id="paymentListId"
                            var="payment"
                            value="#{paymentList}"
                            styleClass="data-table"
                            rowClasses="odd,even"
                            width="100%">
                              <!-- Reimburse -->
                        <s:div rendered="#{payment.reimbursementSummary.allowableReimbursementActionType eq 'SUBMIT_NEW'}">
                            <a4j:commandLink action="#{reimbursementAction.initNewReimbursement(payment)}"
                                             reRender="reimbursePaymentPanel,reimbursePaymentDiv"
                                             limitToList="true">
                                <span> Reimburse</span>
                            </a4j:commandLink>
                        </s:div>
                        <!-- Update Reimburse and Cancel Reimbursement-->
                        <s:div rendered="#{payment.reimbursementSummary.allowableReimbursementActionType eq 'MODIFY_EXISTING'}">
                            <a4j:commandLink action="#{reimbursementAction.initUpdateReimbursement(payment)}"
                                             reRender="reimbursePaymentPanel,reimbursePaymentDiv"
                                             limitToList="true"
                                             bypassUpdates="true">
                                <span>Update Reimbursement</span>
                            </a4j:commandLink>

                            <h:outputText value=" | "/>

                            <a4j:commandLink oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('cancelReimbursementPanel');"
                                             action="#{reimbursementAction.initCancelReimbursement(payment)}"
                                             reRender="cancelReimbursementDiv"
                                             limitToList="true">
                                <span>Cancel Reimbursement</span>
                            </a4j:commandLink>
                        </s:div>

                    </div>
                </rich:column>

            </rich:dataTable>
        </s:div>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

The links I am talking about are: `Reimburse` and `Update Reimbursement`. Clicking on the links rerender `reimbursePaymentPanel` which open up the modal with `id=reimbursePaymentPanel` having textbox with `id="reimbursementAmount"`.

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: Please don't post updates to the question as **answers**. You should use `edit` link below the question to update your question. I've moved them all into your question.

Comment: Some of the code was not rendering properly so I thought of splitting them. I will follow the process here on. Thank you BalusC.

Comment: While posting/editing a message, please pay attention to the right hand column. The formatting rules are explained there.

Comment: looks like wastage of mine and others time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I tried that worked.

#### reimbursePaymentModal.xhtml

```
                <s:decorate template="/layout/edit.xhtml">
                    <ui:define name="label">Reimbursement Amount(*)</ui:define>
                    <h:inputText id="reimbursementAmount"
                                 binding="#{reimburseEvent.amountText}"
                                 value="#{reimbursementAction.reimbursement.amount}">
                        <a4j:support event="onblur" action="#{reimbursementAction.validateAmount}"
                                     limitToList="true"/>
                    </h:inputText>
                </s:decorate>
```

#### PaymentList.xhtml

```
                    <s:div rendered="#{payment.reimbursementSummary.allowableReimbursementActionType eq 'SUBMIT_NEW'}">
                        <a4j:commandLink action="#{reimbursementAction.initNewReimbursement(payment)}"
                                         reRender="reimbursePaymentPanel,reimbursePaymentDiv, reimbursementAmount"
                                         actionListener="#{reimbursementAction.clearForm}" immediate="true" limitToList="true"
                                         >
                            <span> Reimburse</span>
                        </a4j:commandLink>
                    </s:div>
```

#### ReimbursementActionBean.java

```
@In(required=false)
private ReimburseEvent reimburseEvent;

//Added 
public void clearForm(ActionEvent event){
   if(reimbursement!=null){
       reimbursement.setAmount(null);
       getReimbursement().setAmount(null);
   }
    reimburseEvent.getAmountText().setSubmittedValue("");
}
```

#### ReimburseEvent.java

```
@Name("reimburseEvent")

@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)

@AutoCreate


public class ReimburseEvent {

    // amountText is binding attribute in the reimbursementPaymentModal. Binding attributes cannot be used in ReimbursementActionBean (Since it is Conversation Scope).
    // So creating ReimburseEvent (Event scope) to support the binding attribute and injecting it to ReimbursementActionBean.

    private UIInput amountText;

    public void setAmountText(UIInput amountText) {
        this.amountText = amountText;
    }

    public UIInput getAmountText() {
        return amountText;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add in the reRender of your a4j:commandLink the id of the text box that you wanna update, which is "reimbursementAmount":

```
<a4j:commandLink
    action="#reimbursementAction.initNewReimbursement(payment)}"                                  
    reRender="reimbursePaymentPanel,reimbursePaymentDiv,**reimbursementAmount**"
    limitToList="true">
  <span>Reimburse</span>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

If this didn't work, try to include the modalPanel on the same page, which is "PaymentList.xhtml".

HTH.